# Google Sheets Not Copying Entire Cell Selection

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

I got to be missing something here. When I'm in Google Sheets, I've been CTRL selecting multiple cells to copy into another Google Sheet. But I've run into this problem, where sometimes, I'll go to press CTRL + C to copy my selection, and it only copies a *portion* of my selection.

Here's an example. Only cells 710C and 710D are copied.[image: Only cells 710C and 710D are copied]

I just can't figure out what the heck is going on. Is it the order in which I'm selecting the items?  Is it when I accidentally remove then re-add a cell?

What causes Google Sheets to not copy your entire selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on, you can technically copy more than one range at a time, but they must be in the same row/column.

For example, these work and copy all of the selections:

[image: rows]

[image: col]

[image: both]

But this will only copy your last selection, as it goes across different rows and columns:

[image: doesn't work]

Answer (score 1):

notice the dash border:

[image: 0]

in your case, it makes sense that only <kbd>**`C710:D710`**</kbd> range got pasted because only that range got copied

Comment: To add to this - you can't copy + paste discontinuous ranges. You can only copy one range at a time.